# Is it possible to launch navigation app from webpage on Android?

Tags: android, web-applications, navigation

I'm working on a mobile version of a web app. It mostly just displays info of some stores, but it would be nice if it could send the coordinates to the navigation program instead of just displaying it.

If I just put a link like this:

```
<a href="geo:37.422219,-122.08364?z=14">go there</a>
```

it works, and lauches Google Maps to the given coords. I would like to do the same with the navigation program: user clicks link, navigation lauches and directs user to the given coords. Is this possible?
I tried to change geo: to nav:, navi:, navigation: without luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345">Go There</a>
```

Where arguments can be
saddr : Source Address
daddr : Destination Address

Comment: This still brings up Google Maps and not the navigation app. Besides, I only want to give the destination address, since I want to navigate the user from the location they currently at.

Comment: @Moha I can't find the way to send location to navigation app too. I think it is not possible to send command from web page to open apps in device.
I use the answer of mudit to open map app and then tap on navigate which is work too.

Comment: I am using cordova and above code does not open native google maps. It opens the google map in web browser. Does anyone know how to open native google maps?

Answer (score 2):

You can use window.open();

For **Navigation** -
window.open("google.navigation:q=23.3728831,85.3372199" , '_system');

For **Search** - 
window.open("geo:0,0?q=pizza" , '_system');

*Read Here* - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `geo` in front of the coordinates, try with `google.navigation`, that should work.

Edit: seems like it's not that easy anyways. The WebView seem like it only supports 3 different "schemes": GEO, TEL and MAILTO.

I think you need to look at this example: http://android-er.blogspot.dk/2011/10/run-android-java-code-from-webpage.html where JavaScript is used to invoke some Java code.

Inside the JavaScript function that are invoked from the WebView, you would need to put this code, to open Google Navigation:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=37.422219,-122.08364");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Bear in mind, that you can not use z=14 as Google Navigation apparently doesn't support this functionality.

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. I'm developing a web app written in PHP+HTML+JavaScript, not a native Android app. I'd just like to invoke Google Navigation from my HTML/JavaScript code if that's possible. I am not familiar with java so I wouldn't start and write a native Android app.

Comment: Your question didn't really say anything about not developing a native app ;-) Are you using any framework for development?

Comment: I'm using pure PHP and MySQL. It's not a big project. :)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<a href="geo:49.510843,5.938203299999941?q=49.510843,5.938203299999941">YOUR ADDRESS</a>
```

This works on my websites for Android Devices. I think that apple devices will not work.